# How do spark descide filter order

Tags: apache-spark

What is the criteria of filter order in spark, for example

```
+- Project [myField1#66, myField2#79, myField3#93, myField4#108]
   +- Filter isnotnull(myField1#108)
      +- Filter isnotnull(myField2#93)
```

What makes `myField1` get filter first relative to `myField2`? The most efficient way is to do the filter that have the least resulting rows.

But how does spark know what filter result in the least row without running the filter?